# Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'IComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I get rid of the error `Property 'reduce' does not exist on type 'IComponent'` on my method. Initially, `components` had an any type, so it worked fine. But now that I am strongly typing all my methods ad variables I am seeing issues.

```
  static addPlaceholdersOnMultiplePages(components: IComponent[]): IComponent[] {
    return components.map((obj) =>
      obj.reduce(
        (r, a) =>
          r.concat(a, {
            componentIndex: null,
            componentName: ActiveComponentsPartialSelector.Placeholder,
            componentId: `${ActiveComponents.Placeholder}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(8)}`,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          }),
        [
          {
            componentIndex: null,
            componentName: ActiveComponentsPartialSelector.Placeholder,
            componentId: `${ActiveComponents.Placeholder}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(8)}`,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          },
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

My interface is as follows:

```
export interface IComponent
  extends IComponentDetail {
}
```

Comment: expected value out of this reduce?

Comment: An array of IComponent

Comment: reduce never gives a array, it reduces a array into 1 value.

Comment: can you give original array and expected array?

Comment: try answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
static addPlaceholdersOnMultiplePages(components: IComponent[]): IComponent[] {
    return components.reduce(
        (r, a) =>
          r.concat(a, {
            componentIndex: null,
            componentName: ActiveComponentsPartialSelector.Placeholder,
            componentId: `${ActiveComponents.Placeholder}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(8)}`,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          }),
        [
          {
            componentIndex: null,
            componentName: ActiveComponentsPartialSelector.Placeholder,
            componentId: `${ActiveComponents.Placeholder}-${UtilService.generateRandomString(8)}`,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          },
        ],
      )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  return components.map((obj) =>
      obj.reduce(
      //...
```

`obj` here is not an array anymore so you can't use `reduce` function. Not really sure what your function does, maybe remove the `map` function and replace it with the `reduce` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
return components.map((obj) =>

[...Array(components[obj])].reduce( //...
```

Comment: I get the error `Type 'IComponent' cannot be used as an index type.`

Comment: i have modify the answer please check.